# cannot run rails g mongoid:config command .>>undefined method error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, windows, mongodb, mongoid

I'm having trouble running this command on windows 7 32bit , although it worked before-in practice assignments- ,surprisingly , it gives me error now .

I have only created a new app, added mongoid to gem file and ran bundle ,but it gave me error when running  `rails g mongoid:config`

[error log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b9VeZ.png)

And here is my gemfile

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'


# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '4.2.4'
# Use sqlite3 as the database for Active Record
gem 'sqlite3'
# Use Puma as the app server
gem 'puma', '~> 3.0'
# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
# Use CoffeeScript for .coffee assets and views
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.2'
# See https://github.com/rails/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
# gem 'therubyracer', platforms: :ruby

# Use jquery as the JavaScript library
gem 'jquery-rails'
# Turbolinks makes navigating your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/turbolinks/turbolinks
gem 'turbolinks', '~> 5'
# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.5'
# Use Redis adapter to run Action Cable in production
# gem 'redis', '~> 3.0'
# Use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'

# Use Capistrano for deployment
# gem 'capistrano-rails', group: :development
gem 'mongoid', '~> 5.0.0'
group :development, :test do
  # Call 'byebug' anywhere in the code to stop execution and get a debugger console
  gem 'byebug', platform: :mri
end

group :development do
  # Access an IRB console on exception pages or by using <%= console %> anywhere in the code.
  gem 'web-console'
end

# Windows does not include zoneinfo files, so bundle the tzinfo-data gem
gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:mingw, :mswin, :x64_mingw, :jruby]
```

please ,if you need more info , leave a comment. I have searched for similar problems , but solutions didn't worked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On http://guides.rubyonrails.org/upgrading_ruby_on_rails.html (2.19.8) it is written

> When using Ruby 2.4, you can preserve the timezone of the receiver when calling to_time.

But this is a Rails 5 feature but you are running rains 4.2.4. Somehow `ActiveSupport.to_time_preserves_timezone`is set , i.e in a initializer. Try to set this to false. Try to find and delete it.